# add banner to site

Tags: networking, security, http

We have some unusual task in our office. There is a list of domains(about 1000 items).
When a user from our LAN visits one of this domains, we have to add a small banner to the page he sees. Is it possible to do it with a proxy or some other  way?
Thanks!

Comment: yes! I have no idea how off the top of my head, though. Might be able to apply the 'upsidedownternet' concept, though - http://ex-parrot.com/~pete/upside-down-ternet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to do with a content-inspecting proxy (something which can easily be made transparent).

**However** you can't rely on the banner being seen as there's a whole bunch of weird CSS/JS things the web site could be doing.

Straight blocking might be a better idea.

Comment: What proxy can do it?
"Straight blocking" is not our goal, we don't want to block this domains, we want user to know, that domain belongs to some list!

Comment: Squid can - http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation